# Edit during deletion period for corrections/improvements

Tags: discussion, editing, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Due to an error noticed too late after posting, can the OP opt to edit to correct it while delete is active, before re-posting?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. In case it's that: The sequence of events "1. notice error, 2. delete answer, 3. edit to fix error, 4. undelete answer" is quite common.

Comment: Thanks.  that is what I asked, and in fact practising it on occasion. But suddenly I got a msg saying " undelete and then only edit !"  as if incognito edit is not appropriate.

Comment: No idea what "incognito edit" could mean. Are you using a mobile app or something?

Comment: No sir, A lot of edits bumping to top of site by too many small edits esp. by new entry users should be avoided. ( All edits  when done in the invisible /delete mode I called  incognito )Their delivery back as one undelete shot restore is better.

Comment: Does it happen for deleted question or deleted answer? Could you provide a screenshot? I have just tried to edit an answer which was deleted and I got no warning.

Comment: I did n't capture it, Right now all is well. Just got a feeling whether all along I was violative. But if it recurs, shall flag to meta moderator here.

Comment: Was it a question where this happened? If I understand correctly [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179769), users below 10k are not able to edit the self-deleted questions. (The post is from 2011, so thing might have changed since then.)

Comment: However, I assume that [faq posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) should be kept up-to-date. *"Self-deleted posts can be viewed and undeleted by their original authors. However, self-deleted questions cannot be edited by their authors unless undeleted first. Self-deleted answers can be edited by the author without undeleting."*

Answer (score 1):

Questions cannot be edited when they are deleted. (Answers can be edited in such cases.)

From this faq post on meta: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> Self-deleted posts can be viewed and undeleted by their original authors. However, self-deleted questions cannot be edited by their authors unless undeleted first. Self-deleted answers can be edited by the author without undeleting.

---

I have tested this on my own question, which is deleted. I cannot edit it - the edit link is inactive. When I hover over it, I can read in the tooltip: "You cannot edit your own deleted question. Undelete before editing."

[image: screenshot with the tooltip]